# How to find the right php.ini that your Apache is using?

Tags: php, macos

I'm a bit confuse on my PHP versions on my local Mac OS X.

When I ran

```
⚡️  ~  which php                                                                                                 
/usr/local/php5/bin/php                                                                                         
⚡️  ~  php --version                                                                                             
PHP 7.3.8 (cli) (built: Aug 11 2019 20:50:16) ( NTS )                                                           
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group                                                                           
Zend Engine v3.3.8, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies                                                   
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.8, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies                                     
    with Xdebug v2.7.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans                                              
⚡️  ~
```

so this means my CLI version is `5` or `7.3` ??  !

---

When I run

```
php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
```

I got

256M

the result of that matched with my Apache PHP

See picture below

[image]

phpinfo()

[image]

I really need to update the meory_limit.
How do I find `php.ini` of my Apache use?

---

## Updated

I tried to modify `/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini`

and set `memory_limit = 40096M` ~40GB

[image]

I never see that settings take place.

Comment: it literally shows you the 'ini' files used in the next couple lines

Comment: When I tried to modify that it won't affect, are you referring to ` /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini` ?

Comment: Have you restarted your Webserver after changing it? Depending on how you transport requests from Apache to PHP it may be necessary. And dude, PHP5?

Comment: Side note: If you are on mac, why not use **Laravel Valet** https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/valet? And as @LukasWerner suggests you should restart Apache after you make any changes to php.ini for the changes to take effect

Comment: There is also Laravel Sail if you want to use docker

Comment: @LukasWerner : I've been want to upgrade my local PHP, but never get a chance (will take care of it tongiht!). `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart` I restarted with that command.

Comment: @Donkarnash I heard a lot about it, will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @LukasWerner As you can see my CLI on mac is `PHP 7.3.8 (cli)` How do I make my Apache use that version ?

Comment: Hard to say as I cannot see if you use libapachemod-php or php-fpm or something else. But in general just install the proper 7.3 package and uninstall the 5.6 package

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should just rename `/usr/local/php5` to `/usr/local/php` and the confusion is gone ;)

On your phpinfo() page is a section called "Loaded Configuration File" and "Additional .ini files parsed". These are the files to edit.

I am not sure if there is an upper limit for `memory_limit`. Maybe just try to set it to `-1` to disable it.

Some php installations use different .ini files for running in a cli and running in a browser, to check what .ini files are used on command line use `php --ini`.